# How do I set up OpenVPN on CyanogenMod 7?

Tags: cyanogenmod, networking, privacy, vpn, openvpn

I want to route *all* my network traffic through my home's ISP connection when I'm out in Internet cafes so I can't be eavesdropped/[firesheeped](http://codebutler.com/firesheep).

I have an HTC G2 with [CyanogenMod 7](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/), which [has OpenVPN client support built-in](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/OpenVPN):

[image]

At home, I have a router with [TomatoVPN](http://tomatovpn.keithmoyer.com/) on it, which includes an OpenVPN server:

[image]

Now, how do I get the phone client to connect to the router server?  I can Google and find [a set of seemingly relevant instructions](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/OpenVPN), but they aren't very helpful:

> You need to pack your cert and keys and put it in SD card

Where do I get those?

> Copy client.p12 to sdcard root directory

Where do I get that?

> add your certificates, and set the interface type and the protocol accordingly.

How, specifically?  Which settings should be what?  Using settings that don't protect me is worse than no protection at all due to the false sense of security.

I'm looking for step-by-step instructions for a "roadwarrior" setup that routes all traffic through the VPN.

Where do I get keys?  Do I need to use additional username/password authentication? What DNS search domains? What settings should I use in CM7's OpenVPN Advanced menu?  "Redirect gateway" needs to be set to route all traffic, for instance, right?  Which settings for Basic and Advanced in TomatoVPN?  "Direct clients to redirect Internet traffic"? "Respond to DNS"?

**Update:**

I've given it yet another try on my own, and was again unsuccessful.  I don't think there's any way to generate keys on either the router or the phone, so I tried to generate them in Ubuntu.  I tried to follow [these directions](http://www.openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#pki) to generate keys, but they aren't correct.  (The folder is `/usr/share/doc/openvpn/examples/easy-rsa/2.0` instead of `/usr/share/doc/openvpn-2.0/easy-rsa`, for instance, and there's a `vars`, but no `init-config` script.)  I found [these directions](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/openvpn.html), which are more helpful, and generated a number of files:

- 01.pem
- 02.pem
- ca.crt
- ca.key
- dh1024.pem
- htc_g2.crt
- htc_g2.csr
- htc_g2.key
- server.crt
- server.csr
- server.key
- ta.key

The files I copied to the router are

- ca.crt
- server.crt
- server.key
- dh1024.pem

first stripping everything before `-----BEGIN`, according to [these instructions](http://www.wasagacomputers.com/home/2010/8/10/tutorial-site-to-site-vpn-using-tomato-firmware-and-openvpn.html).  The router server starts now and says

> Name  Value
>   Max bcast/mcast queue length  0

under Status.  So I guess the server is working?

Then I copied these files to the phone:

- ca.crt
- htc_g2.crt
- htc_g2.key
- server.crt
- ta.key

Different directions disagree on which files to copy.  Then I went to Settings → Location & security → Install from SD card, and was able to install the CA certificate, added a password, etc.  Trying to add the htc_g2 or server certificates did not work, saying "no certificate to install".  I edited the files and removed everything before `-----BEGIN`, and then they installed.  In "Add OpenVPN VPN", I selected the "ca" certificate for "Set CA certificate", and the htc_g2 certificate for "Set user certificate".  When I try to connect, it says "Unable to connect to network".  Same if I try the server certificate for the user certificate.

Comment: What operating system(s) are you running on your home computer(s)?

Comment: @JonnyP:  
Home computer is Ubuntu but I'd rather use the router than the computer.

Comment: At this stage I'd recommend that you try to get the OpenVPN setup working with a regular OpenVPN desktop client first, and then copy the same setup to your phone.

Comment: I can't believe that no one knows how to do this.  Why does the option exist if no one has ever used it?

Comment: I have a friend that set it up...on CM *6*. He had to re-issue all VPN certs after he found that the CM client required certain fields to be set. I'll see if I can get more info out of him.

Comment: you haven't packaged your client key yet: `openssl pkcs12 -export -in htc_g2.crt -inkey htc_g2.key -certfile ca.crt -out htc_g2.p12`

Comment: Its not an Android issue just because you need to connect an Android device with OpenVPN server... Ask at ServerFault.com.. There you can get better help..

Comment: This question is specific to CM 7. The process is different for newer versions of CM (currently at version 10.1).  If you still want help with this issue, feel free to update your question and I'll walk you through the process.

Comment: @briankb: I have a G2, for which the only version available is 7. http://get.cm/?device=vision

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check the `Keys` tab in TomatoVPN to see if you already have some default keys defined. If not, check out the [OpenVPN HOWTO](http://www.openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#pki) for info on how to generate the keys. Next, copy the first two keys (CA and Server certificate) from the text areas to a text editor and save them with `.cer` suffix and transfer them to your phone. CM7 should be able to import `.cer` certificates directly but older versions may need to use .p12 files (see [this](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html) link for info on how to convert `.crt -> .pem ->.p12`). After this, go to `Settings -> Security -> Install from SD Card` to load the certificates to the phone.

Comment: That link has 14,000 words. Can you point me directly to the relevant parts?  Is the key generation different if I want to connect other computers to my router besides the phone?  I added more details to the question.

Comment: The same keys are used on normal clients as well.I have no experience of TomatoVPN, but you should be able to set at least a couple of different client keys. Also, it could be possible to use the same keys simultaneously on different devices, but this depends on the OpenVPN setup. The key creation is described under the title "Setting up your own Certificate Authority (CA) and generating certificates and keys for an OpenVPN server and multiple clients". If you use keys and keep them safe no user/pass authentication is necessary under usual circumstances. Redirect gateway`should be the only...

Comment: ...one you need to change in CM7 settings.

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Answer (score 1):

OK, so let's clarify the problem.

Can you please explain which file is for? For example, what is the "ta.key" for?

Normally, there's the file list on Server's side:

1. server.conf (the configuration of server, seemed you haven't got
   this file?)
2. ca.crt
3. ca.key
4. dh1024.pem

and the server should also contain a set of client keys.

For the client side, it should have:

1. client.crt
2. client.key
3. ca.crt
4. client.ovpn(or client.conf)

I cannot see why you have ta.key?

for how to create the p12 files, here's the instruction:

Open a Linux terminal(NOTE: you should have OpenSSL pre-installed), enter

> openssl pkcs12 -export -in [PathToClientCert] -inkey [PathToClientKey]
>   -certfile [PathToCACert] -name [FriendlyName] -out certs.p12

(you should replace the contents of square brackets with yours and no need to keep any square brackets.)

then the p12 file named certs.p12 will be generated.

Hope it will helps.

Comment: I don't know what ta.key is.  The server seems to be running ok.  I just don't know how to connect to it.  `/tmp/etc/openvpn/server1` has these files in it: `ca.crt      config.ovpn  dh.pem       server.crt   server.key   status`.  Maybe `config.ovpn` is the same as `server.conf`?

Comment: @endolith yes, config.ovpn is the same as sever.conf. You may need to edit config.ovpn before start the OpenVPN.

Comment: @endolith do you want to connect to OpenVPN from a CM7 android phone or somewhere else?

Comment: The router is running an OpenVPN server and I want to connect to it with my CM7 phone, yes.

Comment: @endolith First, use the command I provided to generate the p12 file, copy it to your phone's SD card. Follow this on Phone's menu: Settings-Wireless & Networks-VPN Settings-Add VPN, then choose 
OpenVPNAdd VPN, and fill in the options:

[VPN name] any as you like

[Set VPN server] fill the IP address, as same as the "remote" in client.ovpn

[User authentication] if you use user/password, fill it.

[Set CA certificate] touch & import the ca cert

[Set user certificate] touch & import the user cert(client.crt)

You may need to check advanced options. That's all.